# How to calculate different avg for the same record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of `venue` where different `teams` can play a `match`. Now, a `team` for each `match` can get an `attendance` for the `venue`, so I'm trying to calculate the `AVG` of the `attendance`, the problem is that I get the result grouped for one `venue`, that's because I used an aggregate function and I'm forced to use `GROUP BY`, the query should return instead the same `venue` but for different `teams` and with different `AVG attendance` of course.

*Query*

```
SELECT m.venue_id,
MIN(m.venue_attendance) AS min_attendance,
MAX(m.venue_attendance) AS max_attendance,
SUM(m.venue_attendance) AS venue_sum,
v.name AS venue_name,
ROUND(AVG(m.venue_attendance), 2) AS average,
v.capacity, t.name AS team_name
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN venue v ON v.id = m.venue_id
INNER JOIN team_info i ON i.venue_id = m.venue_id
INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = i.team_id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
GROUP BY m.venue_id, t.name
ORDER BY average DESC
```

*Data Sample*

**match**

```
id      | round_id | home_team_id | away_team_id | venue_id | venue_attendance
2506177     28            70             71           10           6000
2506195     28            70             76           10            500
2506204     28            70             69           10           2000
2506219     28            70             72           10            500
2506230     28            70           2517           10            300
2506235     28            70           2522           10            500
2506244     28            70          10049           10            400
2506252     28            70          12573           10           6000
2506258     28          2518             70           10           4500
2506267     28            70             71           10           1000
2506285     28            70             76           10            700
2506294     28            70             69           10           1500
2506303     28            70           2518           10           2500
2506309     28            70             72           10           1200
2506320     28            70           2517           10           1200
2506325     28            70           2522           10            800
2506334     28            70          10049           10           5500
2506342     28            70          12573           10           1000
```

**venue**

```
id | name                 | address          | zip_code | city    | phone |
10   Stadiumi Loro Boriçi  Rruga Musa Luli 1    4000      Shkodër   NULL
```

**team_info**

```
team_id | venue_id |
  70         10 
2518         10
```

**team**

```
  id | name 
  70   Skënderbeu Korçë
2518   Vllaznia Shkodër
```

*Output*

```
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "300",
    "max_attendance": "6000",
    "venue_sum": "36100",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "2005.56",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Vllaznia Shkodër"
}
```

*Expected output*

```
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "300",
    "max_attendance": "6000",
    "venue_sum": "31600",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "1858",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Vllaznia Shkodër"
},
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "4500",
    "max_attendance": "4500",
    "venue_sum": "4500",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "4500",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Skënderbeu Korçe"
}
```

As you can see the `venue_sum` should be calculated only when the `team` play in home, looking at the field `home_team_id`, and the average is the total of the `venue_sum / matches played by the team`, for example, for `Vllaznia Shkodër` we have as average: 31600 / 17 = 1858.

Full database: https://files.fm/u/2xwgkaxz

For access the data in the example, simply run:

```
SELECT * FROM `match` WHERE round_id = 28
```

How can I handle this?

**scaisEdge answer**:

the solution proposal by scaisEdge works only for elaboration result, infact now the average is correct. The
main problem still persist, infact the actual result of scaisEdge query is this:

```
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "300",
    "max_attendance": "6000",
    "venue_sum": "31600",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "1858.82",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Vllaznia Shkodër"
}
```

there are also other venues, but I want focalize the attention on this, as I said before 
I need to return the same venue for different teams, so I should also get:

```
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "4500",
    "max_attendance": "4500",
    "venue_sum": "4500",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "4500",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Skënderbeu Korçe"
}
```

but I get only:

```
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "300",
    "max_attendance": "6000",
    "venue_sum": "31600",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "1858.82",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Vllaznia Shkodër"
}
```

so the expected final result must include this:

```
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "300",
    "max_attendance": "6000",
    "venue_sum": "31600",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "1858.82",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Vllaznia Shkodër"
},
{
    "venue_id": "10",
    "min_attendance": "4500",
    "max_attendance": "4500",
    "venue_sum": "4500",
    "venue_name": "Stadiumi Loro Boriçi",
    "average": "4500",
    "capacity": "16000",
    "team_name": "Skënderbeu Korçe"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining the `team_info` table using only `venue_id`. This way every row from `match` will be joined with every team in `team_info`. You should add the condition `i.team_id = m.home_team_id` to limit the JOIN to the home team only:

```
SELECT m.venue_id,
MIN(m.venue_attendance) AS min_attendance,
MAX(m.venue_attendance) AS max_attendance,
SUM(m.venue_attendance) AS venue_sum,
v.name AS venue_name,
ROUND(AVG(m.venue_attendance), 2) AS average,
-- v.capacity, -- no such column in sample data
t.name AS team_name
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN venue v ON v.id = m.venue_id
INNER JOIN team_info i 
  ON  i.venue_id = m.venue_id
  AND i.team_id  = m.home_team_id -- this is the fix
INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = i.team_id
WHERE m.round_id = 28
GROUP BY m.venue_id, t.name
ORDER BY average DESC
```

Result:

```
| venue_id | min_attendance | max_attendance | venue_sum |           venue_name | average |        team_name |
|----------|----------------|----------------|-----------|----------------------|---------|------------------|
|       10 |           4500 |           4500 |      4500 | Stadiumi Loro Boriçi |    4500 | Vllaznia Shkodër |
|       10 |            300 |           6000 |     31600 | Stadiumi Loro Boriçi | 1858.82 | Skënderbeu Korçë |
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aaf7c9/1

But you can probably just skip the `team_info` table and join the `team` table directly to `match`:

```
SELECT m.venue_id,
MIN(m.venue_attendance) AS min_attendance,
MAX(m.venue_attendance) AS max_attendance,
SUM(m.venue_attendance) AS venue_sum,
v.name AS venue_name,
ROUND(AVG(m.venue_attendance), 2) AS average,
-- v.capacity, -- no such column in sample data
t.name AS team_name
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN venue v ON v.id = m.venue_id
INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = m.home_team_id  -- this is the fix
WHERE m.round_id = 28
GROUP BY m.venue_id, t.name
ORDER BY average DESC
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

you should join for home_team_id

```
  SELECT m.venue_id,
  MIN(m.venue_attendance) AS min_attendance,
  MAX(m.venue_attendance) AS max_attendance,
  SUM(m.venue_attendance) AS venue_sum,
  v.name AS venue_name,
  ROUND(AVG(m.venue_attendance), 2) AS average,
  v.capacity, t.name AS team_name
  FROM `match` m
  INNER JOIN venue v ON v.id = m.venue_id
  INNER JOIN team_info i ON i.venue_id = m.venue_id and i.team_id = m.home_team_id
  INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = m.home_team_id
  WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
  GROUP BY m.venue_id, t.name
  ORDER BY average DESC
```

Comment: update your question and add  the actula result from my query and the  expected  result in a tabular way  ..

Comment: you link content have not senso to me .. show a simple tabular text result with proper (clear ) comment  .. and not   a copoy and post of you json  ... semms that you  have not time for a good explanation   of the result  ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176018/discussion-between-jidic-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I updated the question with your solution, maybe is more clear now, I'm also in chat if you have other questions, thanks for you time.

Comment: the group by  m.venue_id, t.name .. should return rows  for each  .. t.name  .. so the result you provided  seems weird  .. check if you read all the resulting rows

Comment: isn't the `GROUP BY` preventing duplicate? so I guess the problem is this, at this point, how to remove the `GROUP BY` using an `aggregate` function?

Comment: I mean the `venue` not the team name

Comment: yep, anyway you can download my database and try yourself: https://files.fm/u/2xwgkaxz for access the data in the post you can do `SELECT * FROM match WHERE round_id = 28`

Comment: You have only one venue name and this must be repeated  in each row .. is SQL the duplication must be evaluated across the entori value mentioned  in group by  ..so  check if you really have duplicated  value or only the normal repeatetion for a partil grouped  column  value

Comment: Not each row, for each team that played in this `venue`

Answer (score 1):

I think to get the stadium several time in the query you have to use analytical functions instead of group by clause.

```
SELECT
    venue_id,
    min_attendance,
    max_attendance,
    venue_sum,
    venue_name,
    round(average,2) AS average,
    team_name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.venue_id,
            MIN(m.venue_attendance) OVER(
                PARTITION BY home_team_id
            ) AS min_attendance,
            MAX(m.venue_attendance) OVER(
                PARTITION BY home_team_id
            ) AS max_attendance,
            SUM(m.venue_attendance) OVER(
                PARTITION BY home_team_id
            ) AS venue_sum,
            v.name AS venue_name,
            AVG(m.venue_attendance) OVER(
                PARTITION BY home_team_id
                ORDER BY
                    NULL
            ) AS average,
  --M.capacity, 
            t.name AS team_name
        FROM
            match m
            INNER JOIN venue v ON v.id = m.venue_id
            INNER JOIN team_info i ON i.venue_id = m.venue_id
                                      AND i.team_id = m.home_team_id
            INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = m.home_team_id
        WHERE
            m.round_id =:round_id
    )
ORDER BY
    average DESC;
```

Hope it helps.

Regards
Ankit

Comment: with your query I get: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
                PARTITION BY home_team_id
            ) AS min_attendance,
' at line 13`

Answer (score 1):

If you want this per team, you are going to need to split each rows into two rows -- one for the home team, one for the away team.

Here are the results per venue per team:

```
select venue_id, team_id,
       min(venue_attendance),
       max(venue_attendance),
       avg(venue_attendance)
from ((select m.venue_id, m.home_team_id as team_id, venue_attendance
       from match m
      ) union all
      (select m.venue_id, m.away_team_id as team_id, venue_attendance
       from match m
      )
     ) m
group by venue_id, team_id;
```

I'll let you work on using joins to get the names and capacity into the query.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67d8d1/2) is a simplified SQL Fiddle, showing the results by venue and team.  The only difference from the above query is `matches` instead of `match`, because the latter is a reserved word.

Comment: with your query I get a really weird result: https://pastebin.com/KpQdsz1p

Comment: @Jidic . . . That would only seem possible if `venue_attendance` where `NULL` in all the `match` records.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: is a bit difficult for me provide a fiddle, I exported the entire database: https://files.fm/u/2xwgkaxz you can see the record of the question by using `SELECT * FROM match WHERE round_id = 28`

Comment: I saw your edit but in my production database won't work, have you tried my database? could you please take a look at it?